# how the System.out.println works?

Tags: java

System is a class and out is a static reference variable in the system class that will gives the reference for the printstrem class to access println method. How the printstrem object is created and gives referance to the out static variable.

Answer (score 3):

`System.out` is a bit special. Even though it's a `final` field, it's manipulated by native code - which is how `System.setOut` is able to work.

When the `System` class is initialized, `System.out` is initialized in native code to a reference to an appropriate stream which will write to the console.

In the JDK 7 code that I'm looking at, there's a `private static void initializeSystemClass` method which is executed by the VM *after* the normal static initializers. That contains:

```
FileOutputStream fdOut = new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out);
setOut0(new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fdOut, 128), true));
```

... where `setOut0` is a native method which will change the value of `System.out`.

Comment: When that printStrem reference will create

Comment: @Venkataramareddy: I'm not sure what your comment means, but I've added some more details.

Answer (score 2):

System class has private constructor so that you cannot instantiate it.

```
private System() {
}
```

Secondly it has out as a static final instance variable of class PrintStream.

```
public final static PrintStream out = null;
```

Now in this PrintStream class you have further functions like

```
public void println(String x) {
    synchronized (this) {
        print(x);
        newLine();
    }
}
```

Where is this out Object instantiated?

It is a native call. So we cannot know it's exact code.

```
private static native void setOut0(PrintStream out);
```

But if you wish to change the default standard" output stream you can call

```
public static void setOut(PrintStream out) {
    checkIO();
    setOut0(out);
}
```

again in System class.

Comment: public final static PrintStream out = null; how it will get reference for printstream class thank u

Comment: @Venkataramareddy added to the answer. Do check!

Comment: i checked in checkIO(); method i am really not understand where he is taking refrence .

Comment: could u plz expline me wht u mean by neative call

Comment: @Venkataramareddy Reference is set in **setOut0(out);** method. **checkIO();** method is for checking security permissions.

Comment: @Venkataramareddy native call means the code is implemented or embedded in JMV. We cannot see its code. All we know is it's behavior(I/O).

Answer (score 0):

`System` is a predefined class in `java.lang` package with `out` as static reference variable holds `PrintStream` class object,`println` methods are overrloaded.

Once JVM hits control to `System.out.println` line `System` class is loaded into runtime memory and static variable ie `out` referred to `PrintStream` class object is instantiated then overloaded `println` methods are being called on it 
this all process happens only once except `println` methods are called one or n times.

Answer (score 0):

• System is a class in the java.lang package.

• out is a static member of the System class, and is an instance of java.io.PrintStream.

• println is a method of java.io.PrintStream. This method is overloaded to print message to output destination, which is typically a console or file.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will give you a brief idea about how `System.out.println` works:

```
class PrintStreamTest{  // PrintStream class

    public void printlnTest(String s) {  //Print() method
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}

public class SystemOutPrintExample { // System class
    public static final PrintStreamTest outTest=new PrintStreamTest(); // out variable


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SystemOutPrintExample.outTest.printlnTest("hai brother...."); 
      }
}
```